# Olingo: can't get @EdmFunctionImport working

Tags: function, odata, olingo

I'm working with Olingo and I'd say everything is fine except the one thing: haven't found a way to get function, attributed with @EdmFunctionImport, working.

I'm using a pure annotation approach, not JPA, so I don't have ODataJPAContext as it's described [here](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/jpafunctionimport.html). And I assume that `AnnotationEdmProvider edmProvider = new AnnotationEdmProvider(AnnotationInstances.MODEL_PACKAGE);` should find my functions, that described with @EdmFunctionImport attribute.

Google has nothing about it. May be someone have such experience?

Answer (score 0):

So far there aren't any official support for function import for Annotation Processor Extension for Olingo.

However if you go thru the issue list there are some code contribution available which require some changes into the annotation-core.jar to enable the function import. You may refer the link here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-651?jql=project%20%3D%20OLINGO%20AND%20component%20%3D%20odata2-annotation%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20ORDER%20BY%20due%20ASC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC

Comment: Thank you! I made it working earlier almost in the same way, but my code is a bit more complicated, because it is using return and parameters types parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I made it working earlier almost in the same way, but my code is a bit more complicated, because it is using return and parameters types parsing.
As a base I’ve used methods for the JPA functions support.
Here is my code (took the first part as it is by earlier link):

2) Add a new method in the container builder class

```
public ContainerBuilder addFunctionImport(
            final FunctionImport functionImport) {
        functionImports.add(functionImport);
        return this;
    }
```

3) Modified the handleEntityContainer method in AnnotationEdmProvider class as follows.

```
private void handleEntityContainer(final Class<?> aClass) {
    EdmEntityType entityType = aClass.getAnnotation(EdmEntityType.class);
    if (entityType != null) {
        FullQualifiedName typeName = createFqnForEntityType(aClass);
        String containerName = ANNOTATION_HELPER
                .extractContainerName(aClass);
        ContainerBuilder builder = containerName2ContainerBuilder
                .get(containerName);
        if (builder == null) {
            builder = ContainerBuilder.init(typeName.getNamespace(),
                    containerName);
            containerName2ContainerBuilder.put(containerName, builder);
        }
        EdmEntitySet entitySet = aClass.getAnnotation(EdmEntitySet.class);
        if (entitySet != null) {
            builder.addEntitySet(createEntitySet(typeName, aClass));
        }

        buildFunctionImports(aClass, builder);
    }
}
private void buildFunctionImports(Class aClass, ContainerBuilder builder) {
        for (int i = 0; i < aClass.getMethods().length; i++) {
            Method method = aClass.getMethods()[i];

        EdmFunctionImport edmAnnotationFunctionImport = method
                .getAnnotation(EdmFunctionImport.class);
        if (edmAnnotationFunctionImport != null
                && edmAnnotationFunctionImport.returnType() != null) {

            try {

                FunctionImport fi = new FunctionImport();
                fi.setEntitySet(edmAnnotationFunctionImport.entitySet());
                fi.setHttpMethod(edmAnnotationFunctionImport.httpMethod().name()); 
                fi.setName(edmAnnotationFunctionImport.name()); 
                builder.addFunctionImport(fi); 


                builder.addFunctionImport(buildEdmFunctionImport(method,
                        edmAnnotationFunctionImport));
            } catch (ODataAnnotationException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}

private FunctionImport buildEdmFunctionImport(final Method method,
        final EdmFunctionImport edmAnnotationFunctionImport)
        throws ODataAnnotationException {
    if (edmAnnotationFunctionImport != null
            && edmAnnotationFunctionImport.returnType() != null) {
        FunctionImport functionImport = new FunctionImport();

        if (edmAnnotationFunctionImport.name().equals("")) {
            functionImport.setName(method.getName());
        } else {
            functionImport.setName(edmAnnotationFunctionImport.name());
        }

        functionImport.setHttpMethod(edmAnnotationFunctionImport
                .httpMethod().name().toString());

        buildEdmReturnType(functionImport, method,
                edmAnnotationFunctionImport);
        buildEdmParameter(functionImport, method);

        return functionImport;
    }
    return null;
}

private void buildEdmParameter(final FunctionImport functionImport,
        final Method method) throws ODataAnnotationException {
    Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    List<FunctionImportParameter> funcImpList = new ArrayList<FunctionImportParameter>();

    int j = 0;
    for (Annotation[] annotationArr : annotations) {
        Class<?> parameterType = parameterTypes[j++];

        for (Annotation element : annotationArr) {
            if (element instanceof EdmFunctionImportParameter) {
                EdmFunctionImportParameter annotation = (EdmFunctionImportParameter) element;
                FunctionImportParameter functionImportParameter = new FunctionImportParameter();
                if (annotation.name().equals("")) {
                    throw new ODataAnnotationException(
                            "annotation.name().equals(\"\")");
                } else {
                    functionImportParameter.setName(annotation.name());
                }

                functionImportParameter.setType(TypeBuilder
                        .getEdmSimpleType(parameterType));

                Facets facets = new Facets();
                if (annotation.facets().maxLength() > 0) {
                    facets.setMaxLength(annotation.facets().maxLength());
                }
                if (annotation.facets().nullable() == false) {
                    facets.setNullable(false);
                } else {
                    facets.setNullable(true);
                }

                if (annotation.facets().precision() > 0) {
                    facets.setPrecision(annotation.facets().precision());
                }
                if (annotation.facets().scale() >= 0) {
                    facets.setScale(annotation.facets().scale());
                }

                functionImportParameter.setFacets(facets);

                funcImpList.add(functionImportParameter);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!funcImpList.isEmpty()) {
        functionImport.setParameters(funcImpList);
    }
}

private void buildEdmReturnType(final FunctionImport functionImport,
        final Method method,
        final EdmFunctionImport edmAnnotationFunctionImport)
        throws ODataAnnotationException {
    ReturnType returnType = edmAnnotationFunctionImport.returnType();

    if (returnType != null) {
        org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.provider.ReturnType functionReturnType = new org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.provider.ReturnType();

        if (returnType.isCollection()) {
            functionReturnType.setMultiplicity(EdmMultiplicity.MANY);
        } else {
            functionReturnType.setMultiplicity(EdmMultiplicity.ONE);
        }

        if (returnType.type() == ReturnType.Type.ENTITY) {
            String entitySet = edmAnnotationFunctionImport.entitySet();
            if (entitySet.equals("")) {
                throw new ODataAnnotationException("entitySet.equals(\"\")");
            }
            functionImport.setEntitySet(entitySet);
        }

        Class<?> methodReturnType = method.getReturnType();
        if (methodReturnType == null
                || methodReturnType.getName().equals("void")) {
            throw new ODataAnnotationException("Wrong return type");
        }
        switch (returnType.type()) {
        case ENTITY:
            EntityType edmEntityType = null;
            String returnTypeName = null;
            if (returnType.isCollection() == false) {
                returnTypeName = methodReturnType.getSimpleName();
            } else {
                returnTypeName = getReturnTypeSimpleName(method);
            }

            for (Class<?> clazz : annotatedClasses) {
                if (returnTypeName.equals(clazz.getName())) {
                    edmEntityType = getEntityType(createFqnForEntityType(clazz));
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (edmEntityType == null) {
                throw new ODataAnnotationException(
                        "Unable to find an entity type");
            }
            functionReturnType.setTypeName(edmEntityType.getBaseType());
            break;
        case SIMPLE:
            EdmSimpleTypeKind edmSimpleTypeKind = TypeBuilder
                    .getEdmSimpleType(methodReturnType);
            functionReturnType.setTypeName(edmSimpleTypeKind
                    .getFullQualifiedName());

            break;
        case COMPLEX:
            String embeddableTypeName = null;
            ComplexType complexType = null;
            boolean exists = false;

            if (returnType.isCollection() == false) {
                embeddableTypeName = methodReturnType.getName();
            } else {
                embeddableTypeName = getReturnTypeName(method);
            }

            FullQualifiedName fqn = null;
            for (Class<?> clazz : annotatedClasses) {
                if (embeddableTypeName.equals(clazz.getName())) {
                    fqn = ANNOTATION_HELPER.extractComplexTypeFqn(clazz);
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (fqn == null) {
                throw new ODataAnnotationException(
                        "Unable to find an complex type");
            }
            functionReturnType.setTypeName(fqn);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        functionImport.setReturnType(functionReturnType);
    }
}

private String getReturnTypeName(final Method method) {
    try {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) method
                .getGenericReturnType();
        Type t = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return ((Class<?>) t).getName();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return method.getReturnType().getName();
    }
}

private String getReturnTypeSimpleName(final Method method) {
    try {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) method
                .getGenericReturnType();
        Type t = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return ((Class<?>) t).getSimpleName();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return method.getReturnType().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```